# excel vlookup multiple rows into one cell

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I would like to get the data from several rows from one sheet [sheet1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x4ybb.png) into a single cell on another sheet [sheet2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FaLPQ.png) based on a lookup.

For example there is data on one sheet :

[sheet1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x4ybb.png)

And I would like to lookup data based on id and return all the concerning rows into one cell like this:

[sheet2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FaLPQ.png)

Is that possible with an excel formula or is this only solvable with VBA?

Thank you for your help in advance.

I found a vba that came close to a solution but didn't work. I've looked at "index, match" functions "small" functions but could find a solution that puts data into a single cell...

This is the vba code I found that came close to solution:

```
'Function SingleCellExtract(Lookupvalue As String, LookupRange As Range, ColumnNumber As Integer)
  Dim i As Long
  Dim Result As String
  For i = 1 To LookupRange.Columns(1).Cells.Count
  If LookupRange.Cells(i, 1) = Lookupvalue Then
  Result = Result & " " & LookupRange.Cells(i, ColumnNumber) & ","
  End If
  Next i
  SingleCellExtract = Left(Result, Len(Result) – 1)
  End Function'
```

the vba threw value or compile errors..   it looks like it only returns values from one vertical column

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> "Is that possible with an excel formula or is this only solvable with VBA?"

It sure is possible through formula, but you'll have to have access to the [`TEXTJOIN`](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/textjoin-function-357b449a-ec91-49d0-80c3-0e8fc845691c) function:

[image]

Formula in `H2`:

```
=TEXTJOIN(CHAR(10),TRUE,IF($A$2:$A$11=G2,$B$2:$B$11&", "&$C$2:$C$11&", "&$D$2:$D$11&", "&$E$2:$E$11,""))
```

> ***Note:*** It's an array formula and need to be confirmed through <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>

Drag the formula down and make sure you got textwrap selected on column H.

No access to `TEXTJOIN`? You can always create your own, for example:

```
Function TEXTJOIN(rng As Range, id As Long) As String

For Each cl In rng
    If cl.Value = id Then
        If TEXTJOIN = "" Then
            TEXTJOIN = cl.Offset(0, 1) & ", " & cl.Offset(0, 2) & ", " & cl.Offset(0, 3) & ", " & cl.Offset(0, 4)
        Else
            TEXTJOIN = TEXTJOIN & Chr(10) & cl.Offset(0, 1) & ", " & cl.Offset(0, 2) & ", " & cl.Offset(0, 3) & ", " & cl.Offset(0, 4)
        End If
    End If
Next cl

End Function
```

In cell `H2` you can call the UDF through `=TEXTJOINS($A$2:$A$11,G2)` and drag down. Again, make sure textwrapping is checked for the column.

**EDIT:**

As per OP's comment, this is how I got the data to show correctly:

- Select column `H` and click textwrap + top alignment as shown in this screenshot:

[image]

- Next, select all cells if result is not correct yet:

[image]

- Double-click the line between columns and rows to space them to fit the data

Comment: oh wow, this formula works great JvdV! Thanks again :) One small thing I'm missing here. I use office 365 and I selected textwrap for culumn H. The first row with bananas is copied good, for grapes only the first row is visible and for apples the second row of grapes appears when dragging down and after that it disappears. Could it be a setting?

Comment: hello JvdV, I need to get back on this one with you. Wrapping text on the column doesn't work for me. I tried several alignment settings but no luck either. Can you share the (wrap / alignment) settings you have?

Comment: @Tom, see my edited answer. This gave me the correctly displayed data :)

Comment: hello JvdV, must be me or the excel version I use but I can't fix it. I've got the top align and text wrap selected as can be seen in the picture (and selected all cells and double clicked between the columns and rows for auto fit) Anyone have a similar problem?

Comment: @Tom, I can see by your screenshot you have not entered the formula as an array through CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER. That's your problem. Follow my answer precisely, and when you done typing the formula, don't just press enter. Hold down the ctrl and shift keys first before pressing enter. That will make these curly brackets appear to confirm you done it correctly.

Comment: what a newbie to excel mistake :) tnx ;)